# Difference between Windows Server and a regular Linux distribution

Tags: windows-server-2008, smb, windows-server

We need a server at work just to set up an SMB shared folder and to run just one application, what would be the difference between buying a server that runs Windows Server 2008 and building a custom machine with server-grade hardware that runs any regular Linux distro?? (Apart from the incompatibility of binaries).

Comment: This question seems overall broad.  Its the same differences between running Linux and Windows, or OS X and Windows.

Comment: Not entirely, and if we put it that way it'd also be the difference between running android and Linux or similar, but I'm taking about servers

Comment: Which is the reason I believe this question to be broad.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to know what's the difference between a "server" os like windows server and a linux-based os.

Comment: There is hardly any different between a server version of Linux and a desktop version of Linux.  The server version just would have less accessibility applications installed by default.

Comment: Is that so? But what's the difference between windows server and Linux?

Comment: There isn't any.

Comment: Do you have any references? I'd like to dig more into this but I just don't the right words to start searching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main difference would be Hardware Support. OSs that are not written for server grade hardware will not take full advantage of said hardware.

Comment: But would that be enough for an smb shares server?

Comment: Yes - you could do the same with a windows box as well... Use server level OSs for servers and desktop level OSs for desktops.